# how to trigger click event in M2

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, knockoutjs

In my header section I have user name and if user have access to different location then he has button saying click me. I want to send ajax call on this button. But JS is not working. Can anybody help me how can I trigger click event on this?

```
<li class="user-name-welcome">
    <span class="user"
          data-role="location-section"
          tabindex="0"
          data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
          data-bind="scope: 'location'">
        <span data-bind="text: location().name"></span>
        <span data-bind="if: location().multilocation">
            (<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="change-location">
            click me
        </a>)
        </span>
    </span>
    </li>`
```

Comment: check my code and let me know if now working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="user-name-welcome">
    <span class="user"
          data-role="location-section"
          tabindex="0"
          data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
          data-bind="scope: 'location'">
        <span data-bind="text: location().name"></span>
        <span data-bind="click: updateLocation">
            click me
        </span>
    </span>
    </li>`
```

Now create "updateLocation" function into respencted js file and from that function you need to call ajax request.

Comment: but in that span I have put an if condition

Comment: you can put that if condition into that updateLocation function according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your html file :

```
<li class="user-name-welcome">
    <span class="user" data-role="location-section" tabindex="0" data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}' data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger-keypress-button="true" data-bind="scope: 'location'">
        <span data-bind="text: location().name"></span>
        <span>
            <!-- ko if: location().multilocation -->
            <span data-bind="click: changeLocation"> click me </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

For ajax call add this js code in your js file :

```
define(['uiComponent','jquery','ko','mage/storage'], function(Component,$,ko,storage) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },
            changeLocation: function () {
                myAjaxCall: function(dataToPass) {
                    fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                    storage.post(
                        'url/of/mycontroller',
                        JSON.stringify(dataToPass),
                        true
                    ).done(
                        console.log("Request complete successfully");
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
});
```

**Deploy content and clean cache.**

I hope it will useful for you.